# Sort merged array consisting of sorted arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I got two sorted arrays e.g. (3,4,5) and (1,3,7,8) and I got the combined sorted array (3,4,5,1,3,7,8).

Now I would like to sort the already combined array, without splitting it, but by overwriting it, by making use of the fact that it consists of 2 arrays which had already been sorted. Is there any way of doing this efficiently? I know there are a lot of threads about how to do this, by iterating through the sorted arrays and then putting the values into the new array accordingly, but I haven't seen this type of question anywhere yet. I would like to do this in c, but any help / pseudocode would be very kindly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The function which would do the sorting, would only be given the combined array and (maybe ) the length of the other two arrays if needed.

Comment: Instead of spending a lot of time to sort that already *merged* array, wouldn't it be sooo much easier to change the code that currently throws your two arrays into the single one? You know, that code could simply do a merge while building up that new array?! Instead of first pulling two arrays into one, to then figure how to efficiently re-sort that.

Comment: I am not getting you. What did you mean by overwriting and without spiting? Why standard quick or marge sort won't be applicable in your case?

Comment: @Sigstop I think he wants to say: I have an array that consists of two sequences of sorted numbers. Is there a way too sort that array based on this knowledge ... without doing a "real" sort; and without creating another new array.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the original sorted arrays, the combined array (note it is *not* sorted) doesn't really help, except in that your destination storage is already allocated.

There's a well-known and very simple algorithm for merging two sorted ranges, but you can just use [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) instead of coding it yourself.

Note that only works for *non-overlapping* input & output ranges: for your amended question, use [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge), with the middle iterator set to the first element from your second sequence:

```
void sort_combined(int *array, size_t total, size_t first) {
    std::inplace_merge(array, array + first, array + total);
}

// and use it like

int combined[] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8};
const size_t first = 3;
const size_t second = 4;
const size_t total = 7; // == sizeof(combined)/sizeof(*combined)

sort_combined(combined, total, first);
```